# How to display an IEnumerable<Class> in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an action method called LoadMoreComments that returns an IEnumerable. I call this action method through jquery in one of my views (code below):

```
    var loadCommentsClicked = function(){
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/LoadMoreComments",
            data: { //Passing my data
            success: function (data)
            {
                //How to display data here
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                alert('Failed to retrieve comment.');
            }
        });
    };
```

Everything works for me and the data is returned to jquery but I have no idea how to retrieve each Comment from the "data" object. Ideally I want to render a partialview from each Comment object, something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    Html.RenderPartial("_CommentCardPartial", Comment);
}
```

But obviously this doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated. 
Edit:
Here is my method's signature:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<Comment>> LoadMoreComments(int userParticipationId, int firstId);
```

Comment: What is `data` (show what your `LoadMoreComments()` method returns). And `Html.RenderPartial()` is server side code - you cannot execute in the client using javascript.

Comment: I edited my question to show the return type. I also conceptually understand that server side code shouldnt be mixed with jquery but really dont know how to call my partial page otherwise.

Comment: So all you need to do is loop though the array and access each property of `Comment` - `$.each(data, function(index, item) { var name = item.Name;` etc. You have not said what you want to do with that data, but it suggests you want to add html to the view, so therefore you should just be returning a partial view.

Comment: I have a partial view that takes a Comment and simply displays its data (e.g. Id, Text, etc.) So I wanted to iterate through "data" object and display each Comment included therein.

Comment: Your method returns `IEnumerable<Comment>` which means you need to iterate through each object, and build html for each property of each object. Why are you not just returning a partial view of the html you want and append it to the DOM?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, and it worked. Thanks for the help. I'm not sure how to mark your comment as a solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135381/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-houman-ag).